# Jackson data-bind not serializing type metadata inside Collection

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I have an abstract Class Abst with 3 concrete classes extending it.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = First.class,
                              name = FIRST),
           @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Second.class,
                              name = SECOND),
           @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Third.class,
                              name = THIRD)})
public abstract class Abst {
    public static final String FIRST = "first";
    public static final String SECOND = "second";
    public static final String THIRD = "third";
```

When I serialized instances of type First.class, Second.class, or Third.class the meta-data '@type' is correctly serialized as `'@type': 'first'` or `@type: 'second'` etc. However, when I have a `List<Abst>` the metadata is not getting serialized.

I found out that when jackson serializes the classes individually it is using a `TypeWrappedSerializer` while when it serailizes a List it uses `IndexListSerializer` with individual elements being serialized by `BeanSerializer` instead of `TypeWrappedSerializer`. Is there any extra annotation or something I am missing above?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why this was happening, but I resolved it by simply creating a custom serializer that would add the metadata during serialization. Everything worked as is.